# 3 SharePoint HOWTO questions for the community

Tags: sharepoint

1. If I have a list containing NAME and EMAIL of approximately 10 rows, is there a workflow work-around allowing me to send an email to all recipients of the “selected view” of the list?  The scenario involves simply browsing the list, opening a link (or clicking a button) that launches a new message in Outlook.  If the above is possible, can I customize the (a) message body with a stored template, (b) carbon copy recipients and (c) message subject?  Have any workarounds to accomplish this?  Trying to do so without any extensions to SP with Visual Studio.  Any links, tips, tricks to accomplishing this?
2. I intentionally created an SP site with external sharing enabled because I wanted any child sites beneath it to be externally accessible.  I want to do so, however, without external users accessing the parent.  Is this possible?
3. I’m exploring opportunity #2 above because I’d like teachers to collect documents from a “shared” read-only folder yet be permitted to create a personal (i.e. team) folder that is writable.  In doing so, I’d like the modified document in their personal folder to be (a) numerically rated and (b) freely tagged with meta attributes.  Thinking here is that team members can search for docs that are associated with the freely created meta data.  Question is, is there a way to propagate all the meta data generated so that users can select/enter it in their subsequent searches?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'll only answer to your 1 (because I don't understand the 2, and the 3 seems too complex to help on a forum like that).

A workflow looks at only one row/item, so you cannot do what you want in that way. At my work I don't have access to the backend programming (C#) so I'm doing everything with JavaScript. In your case you could use JavaScript in this scenario :

- The user goes to a page and click on a button
- A JavaScript code is triggered and gets all the data from the list
- The JavaScript code creates a new item into a special list with the collected data
- There is a workflow tied to this special list that sends an email based on the different fields
- The last step of the workflow is to delete the item from the special list

In this scenario you can use templates for the body, and do all the things you want.
To use JavaScript with Sharepoint you can look at my framework that is called [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) or at the popular [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/).